# Showing the paperclip icon on a particular message when there are no attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

In order to save space, I have different VBA modules designed to automatically remove attachments from sent mail or to manually (on macro run) remove attachments from received mail.  The attachments are saved to my local hard drive and the `Outlook.Mailitem.HTMLBody` is updated with links to the saved attachments.

Naturally, when the attachments are removed from a particular message, the paperclip icon disappears.  I would like the paperclip icon to remain visible for those particular messages despite them no longer having attachments.

I **could** create a small attachment and add that to the message in order to make the icon appear, but I would prefer not to.  Is it possible to manually set the property that causes the paperclip icon to be visible?

I was thinking I could use `PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` to set the `SmartNoAttach` property in such a way that the icon appears, but I am not sure how, nor if it's even possible.

Here is my code that I have in `ThisOutlookSession` that automatically removes attachments from sent mail.  I am not a strong coder so any feedback on this code is welcome.

```
Public WithEvents objSentMails As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Set objSentMails = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objSentMails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objSentMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strAttachmentInfo As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String


On Error Resume Next

    'Only work on emails
    If Item.Class = olMail Then

        Set objSentMail = Item
        strFolderpath = "H:\Desktop\Attachments\Sent\" & Format(objSentMail.SentOn, "yyyy.mm.dd") & "\"


        'creates subdirectory based on sent date
        If Dir(strFolderpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir strFolderpath
        End If

        'converts emails to HTML format
        If objSentMail.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objSentMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            objSentMail.Save
        End If

        Set objAttachments = objSentMail.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count

        strDeletedFiles = ""

        'cycles through all attachments, saves them, and removes them from the message

        If lngCount > 0 Then
            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
                strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
                strFilename = strFile
                strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

                'ignores small files (e.g. embedded social media logos)
                If objAttachments.Item(i).Size > 6000 Then
                    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
                    strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br><a style='color: #ffffff; !important;' href='file://" & strFile & "'>" & strFilename & "</a>"
                    objAttachments.Item(i).Delete
                End If
            Next i

            'Insert the information of removed attachments to the body
            If strDeletedFiles <> "" Then
                '90s style drop-shadow table
                objSentMail.HTMLBody = "<p><table style='border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;'><tr style='height: 5px'><td style='background:#54A5CB; width: 8px'></td><td style='background:#54A5CB; border-color:#54A5CB'></td><td style='background: #54A5CB;'></td><td style='width:8px'></td></tr><tr><td style='background: #54A5CB;'></td><td style='background: #54A5CB; color: #ffffff; padding: 0px; font-family:calibri;'><strong style='font-size: 18px'>Attachments:</strong> " & strDeletedFiles & "</td><td style='background: #54A5CB;'></td><td style='background: #264957; width: 8px'></td></tr><tr style='height: 5px'><td style='background: #54A5CB; width: 8px'></td><td style='background: #54A5CB;'></td><td style='background: #54A5CB;'></td><td style='background: #264957; width:8px'></td></tr><tr style='height: 5px'><td></td><td style='background: #264957'></td><td style='background: #264957'></td><td style='background: #264957'></td></tr></table></p><br>" & objSentMail.HTMLBody
                objSentMail.Save
            End If
        End If
    End If

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objSentMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I am curious to understand why you would even want to do this. Is your intention to mislead or confuse people?

Comment: @braX - this is on my own machine and for my own personal outlook.  When searching emails for a particular attachment, the visual representation of the paperclip icon is very useful.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3627-outlook-search-within-attachments.html

Comment: Thank you, that would be useful although in this case the attachments have already been removed from the message so I'm not able to search their contents within outlook.  I do search within their contents with Windows Explorer in the folder where I have saved all the attachments.  But having the paperclip icon  will visually  let me know which emails USED to have attachments, and when I open the message, the links to the attachments will be there

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue, you can use the [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty) method which sets the property specified by `SchemaName` to the value specified by `Value`.

```
Sub DemoPropertyAccessorSetProperty() 
 Dim myProp As String 
 Dim myValue As Variant 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 'Get first item in the inbox 
 Set oMail = _ 
 Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1) 
 'Name for custom property using the MAPI string namespace 
 myProp = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B" 
 myValue = True 
 'Set value with SetProperty call 
 'If the property does not exist, then SetProperty 
 'adds the property to the object when saved. 
 'The type of the property is the type of the element 
 'passed in myValue. 
 On Error GoTo ErrTrap 
 Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor 
 oPA.SetProperty myProp, myValue 

 'Save the item 
 oMail.Save 
 Exit Sub 
ErrTrap: 
 Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description 
End Sub
```

Comment: This code runs without triggering any errors, but nothing seems to be happening for the first item in my inbox. The paperclip icon behaves as normal.  I used `Msgbox oPA.GetProperty(myProp)` to debug, which returns "True" however even when I comment out the line `oPA.SetProperty myProp, myValue` my `Msgbox` line returns "True" regardless if the first item has attachments or not

Comment: setting `myValue = False` successfully returns a false on Msgbox but the paperclip icon still does not appear.  I've updated the code to run this on whatever mail item I have selected; and have tested it on items with and without attachments, and it appears that the property is being successfully set each time, but the paperclip icon remains unchanged regardless if it's set to True or False